# Pyenv cannot install python on MacOS M1

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

Pyenv will not install any version of python on my system (MacOS M1).

Here's the output from the terminal session:

```
pyenv install 3.9.0
```

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.9.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.0...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.0.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rl/lwsby5952zs1d56sjyj0tcn00000gn/T/python-build.20220602111813.90726
Results logged to /var/folders/rl/lwsby5952zs1d56sjyj0tcn00000gn/T/python-build.20220602111813.90726.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... no
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 8
checking size of pthread_key_t... 8
checking whether pthread_key_t is compatible with int... no
configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

[Terminal Session (Warp)](https://app.warp.dev/block/hQy0IZW2ZQ95W6DZN91ugD)

I tried using the `arch` prefix as well:

```
arch -x86_64 pyenv install 3.8.9
```

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.9.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.9/Python-3.8.9.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.9...
patching file Misc/NEWS.d/next/Build/2021-10-11-16-27-38.bpo-45405.iSfdW5.rst
patching file configure
patching file configure.ac
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.0.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rl/lwsby5952zs1d56sjyj0tcn00000gn/T/python-build.20220602111231.79341
Results logged to /var/folders/rl/lwsby5952zs1d56sjyj0tcn00000gn/T/python-build.20220602111231.79341.log

Last 10 log lines:
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      _PyIntl_textdomain in libpython3.8.a(_localemodule.o)
      _PyIntl_textdomain in libpython3.8.a(_localemodule.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: clang: error: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_testembed] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [python.exe] Error 1
```

Snippet from `.zshrc`:

```
# Pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
# Pyenv-virtualenv
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Pyenv version: `pyenv 2.3.1`

*Update*: Resolved. It was a compatibility issue. `pyenv` doesn't support M1 for older versions of python (3.6/3.7/etc). Installing `3.7.13` or `3.10.0` both work.

Comment: This might be of help: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1876#issuecomment-820996039.

Comment: That was it! It looks like the issue is deeper than just `3.9.0`, the same issue occurs with the younger versions of `3.6`, `3.7` and so on.

Comment: Please answer below rather than editing the question to say "resolved"

Comment: @AniMenon Your edit fixed typos and wording, not syntax; misspelling "grammar" in the edit summary is a common typo, but particularly ironic here. (Other than that, thanks for a useful edit.)

Comment: @tripleee well actually it wasn't Grammar so _Grammer_ :D

Answer (score 2):

I am using M2 Ventura 13.2

1. arch -arm64 pyenv install 3.11.1
2. pyenv virtualenv 3.11.1 artifact
3. pyenv local artifact
4. pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
5. Check in the shell

```py
>>> import torch

>>> torch.backends.mps.is_available()

True
```

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old thread. Did you download `pyenv` and `pyenv-virtualenv` from brew or did you use the curl command?

Comment: From `curl` command.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue trying to install python 3.11.5 with pyenv on mac with an ARM processor. Found a solution on some random Japanese forum :)

0. Make sure you have Rosetta installed (Run `pgrep oahd` in your Terminal, if you see a process number in the output, you are OK)
1. Open Finder, go to Applications, and find Terminal (it could be in the Utilities folder)
2. Right-click on Terminal > Get info.
3. Tick `Open using Rosetta`. Close the window and restart the Terminal.
4. Run `uname -m`. You should see `x86_64` in the output. (If you see `arm64` your Terminal is not running with Rosetta)
5. Run `pyenv install 3.11.5` or another version.